# Simple Form action route is not working on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, simple-form

I'm having a hard time with the Paperclip gem. I'm trying to upload a picture as an avatar for my user. Everytime I upload, it will get the file and store it in the User DB table. I'm trying to get my simple form to go through `action='/users/<%=session[:user_id]%>'`, which then will go through `user#update` (which then will update my users picture), but it just gives me an error:

```
`undefined local variable or method `update_users_path' for '
```

```
form_for @user, :url => update_users_path, :method => patch, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :avatar %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <div class="form-action">
        <%= f.submit :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried to do it without Simple Form, but I need multipart to be true in order to pass back the file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add a bit more of the relevant code so that we can take a look at it to determine where the bug is coming from? Note: edit your question and add the code there, don't use comments as the code-formatting is dreadful.

Comment: do `rake routes | grep user` in console and you might see, that its called `update_user_path`, also you dont need to specify the url if you are `rescources :user`in your routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

The path to update a User is not `update_users_path`, it is `user_path(@user)` with `:method =>:patch` or `:method => :put`. RESTful routing connects `PUT /users/:id` to the `#update` action. Take a look at the [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for more details.

You should be able to build the form properly with just:

```
form_for @user, :method => :patch, :html => {:multipart => true}
```

The URL will be inferred from the `method` and `@user`, or if you do want to include it, use `:url => user_path(@user)`. In fact, because the `@user` already exists, Rails will infer `:method` for you too.

Since you are using `form_for` (and presumably a recent version of Rails), you also don't need to explicitly add `multipart`. As the [Form Helpers guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) indicates, Rails will figure that out from the presence of `f.file_field` and include it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `update_users_path` is not a valid route.

--

The route will be `user_path(@user)` with `method: :patch` (if you're using `resources :users` in the routes)

If you have `@user` populated properly, you shouldn't have issue by just passing it directly to the `form_for` as follows:

```
#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, multipart: true do |f| %>
```